# Switch keyboard layouts with i3

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, ibus

I have a fresh i3 version 4.11 (2015-09-30, branch "4.11") installed over my Ubuntu 16.04. 
Actually I need to use 3 different keyboard layouts for example `en`, `fr` and `ru` with the possibility to switch between them by using some keyboard shortcut.

I have tried some methods but neither was completely satisfactory:

- Using `ibus-daemon` almost works but I cannot use any shortcuts for change layouts.
- My actual setup is configuring `setxkbmap` when I start `i3`:

  ```
  exec --no-startup-id "setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout fr,us,ru -option grp:alt_shift_toggle"
  ```

So I can switch between my layouts but sometimes I have no idea which layout I am actually in use because there is not any tray icon for that in this setup.

For conclusion my needs are:

- Be able to switch layouts by pressing some hotkeys.
- Some indications(preferably, tray icon) for layout I am actually in use.

Is there some work around about this? Or maybe there is some i3 plugin tha t actually does the job? Some third software?

Comment: This is not a window manager task, so don't look in i3 for that. Please do some research, this has been asked and answered before. Anyway, regarding what @shellter said, i3 has a subreddit (i3wm) for these kind of questions.

Comment: @IngoBürk all questions are answered somewhere:) I agree that it's not a window manager task but it's surely a job for desktop environment! So I am looking for some tool(s)/solution that will do what i want in combo with i3. Anyway thank you for subreddit advice, I'll look for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### You can do it with [`xkblayout-state`](https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state) and [`i3blocks`](https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks)

#### For `xkblayout-state`:

I assume you have `git`.

```
~$ git clone https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state.git
~$ cd xkblayout-state
~$ make
```

Now copy compiled `xkblayout-state` somewhere in your `PATH`, for example:

```
~$ `cp xkblayout-state /usr/local/bin/`
```

#### Now for `i3blocks`:

```
sudo apt-get install i3blocks
cp /etc/i3blocks.conf ~/.i3blocks.conf
```

In your `i3` config file (~/.config/i3/config) replace `i3status` with `i3blocks`,

```
# Start i3bar to display a workspace bar (plus the system information i3status
# finds out, if available)
bar {
        status_command i3blocks
        tray_output primary                                               
}
# in case of layout change event - send signal to i3blocks
bindsym ISO_Next_Group exec pkill -RTMIN+1 i3blocks
```

And restart `i3wm` (mod+shift+R), you should now see that `i3blocks` appeared.

Open your `~/.i3blocks.conf` and add somewhere (for example, right above [VOLUME] section):

```
#Language indicator
[language]
#label=LNG
command=xkblayout-state print %s | awk '{print toupper($0)}'
interval=once
signal=1
```

Again, restart i3wm (mod+shift+R), and you should see your locales in status bar, switching.

Check out  `xkblayout-state --help`, there is many options for different output.

Comment: So the key is using i3blocks in place of i3status.

Comment: @Niakrais, the key is _get shit done_. There is many ways, and this is one of them. Current problem - `i3status` is not so flexible (that's why more sane `i3blocks`) and there is no easy way to get current keyboard layout, so - that's why there `xkblayout-state`.Bonuses of such approach: clear, concise. And you can easily change/expand `i3blocks` later. `xkblayout-state` can be easily used somewhere else too.

If you want to stick with `i3status` - you can look here also: https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/4ib2fp/keyboard_layout_and_wifi_signal_level_in_i3bar/

Comment: Sure and it works fine, I ever tried to set a interval to -2 for xkblayout-state's check but It overheats my processor:)

Comment: @Niakrais, yes, thanks to current multi-core technologies and gigs of ram - we can shoot in our leg faster than ever.

If you need to monitor your kbd layout every millisecond - you can do it, but it will be costly.

Comment: @Niakrais, thanks to you, I started digging again - check edited answer now, it's way more better.

Comment: thanks, I had in mind to test iblocks signals tomorrow:)

Answer (score 2):

Follow up to @aring's answer:

> You can do it with xkblayout-state and i3blocks

Switching back and forth between two languages with `xkblayout-state`, put this in your `~/.config/i3/config` file:

```
bindsym $mod+b exec xkblayout-state set $(( $(xkblayout-state print %c) ^ 1 ))
```

Comment: @uchaosis I think, you could post your edit as an answer, quoting existing answer.

Comment: I edited my answer just now to include the quote from @aring's answer.